# Fazer consulta em um arquivo XML - C#

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone, windows-phone-8-1

Tenho uma aplicação em **windows phone 8.1** em que um arquivo XML é exibido em uma `listBox`, e nessa aplicação tem uma `textbox` para o usuário fazer pesquisa do conteúdo que é exibido pela `listbox`.

A minha dúvida é a seguinte: como faço para fazer essa consulta, para que o select abranja todas as tags do meu documento?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu podes fazer um `select` usando **linq**, da seguinte forma:

```
var query = from element in root.Elements
where (string)element.Attribute ("atr") == "search" 
select element;
```

O meu exemplo é uma consulta bem simples, pois, como tu não postou o código que já tens, não sei qual a tua real necessidade.

Answer (score 0):

Pode usar uma sintaxe XPATH [tens um tutorial aqui da sintaxe.](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_syntax.asp)

No C# podes obter escrever a query XPATH usando o [XmlDocument.SelectNodes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb538208(v=vs.110).aspx)